# How to upload Image in website using J-meter script

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

After recording a script in j-meter which uploads an image in website, if i again execute a script than user is able to upload a image which was recorded in script. Now a problem is that how can i upload a new image while executing a script?

Answer (score 0):

1. Locate the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which performs the image upload. Normally the criteria are:

   - `Use multupart-form/data` box is checked
   - There is something in `Files upload` tab

     [image]
2. Once done you should be able to change `File path` to point to the new file and [`MIME Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) if it is different. Remember either to use full path to the new file or copy the new file to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation so JMeter could find it.

Check out [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) article for more information regarding simulating file uploads and downloads in JMeter test scripts.